# How to test credit card shopping in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway, payment-methods

I want to enable the credit card feature so that user can pay through cards.Now when i try on SCC( saved credit card ) information works .I create test account on `http://www.cardsave.net/Developer-Support` and download some test accounts.But when i try same info on Card save  method i got this error `error 261 couldn't communicate with payment gateway`.

Comment: It is Down to Port 4430 being closed on your server. follow the url for details http://developers.paymentsense.co.uk/developers-resources/faq/

Comment: Normally you are not allowed to save credit card data. This is only allowed, when your server, software and infrastructure is PCI complaint!

Comment: please clarify as to what payment extension/paygate you're attempting to configure and test

Answer (score 1):

As commented in the [link provided](http://developers.paymentsense.co.uk/developers-resources/faq/) and also on the [magento forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263632/) but this appears to be an issue with port 4430 not being open on your server.

It also appears to be part of the extension called PaymentSense. If you are using this extension then I would suggest that you have a look into this port, either you can sort this yourself or contact your hosting provider for help with this.